# how to save array data in database in cakephp3?

Tags: cakephp

Hi I'm new in cakephp and i want to save some array data in database 
here is my code

```
 $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        $userdata=[
          'firstname'=>$user['firstname'],
          'lastname'=>$user['lastname'],
            'nationcod'=>$user['nationcod'],
            'usrename'=>$user['username'],
            'password'=>$user['username']
            ];
       $this->Users->save($userdata);
```

but when I test it this error occurred:
                     Call to a member function errors() on array.
I just wanna change user posted data and save it in the users table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assigned `$user` with `$this->Users->newEntity();`. And afterwords you are using `$user['firstname']`. There won't be anything in it as it is an entity not array. From your question I guess that you want to keep user's username as their password. So all you have to do is this.

```
$user=$this->Users->newEntity();
if($this->request->is('post')){
    $this->request->data['password']=$this->request->data['username'];
    $user=$this->Users->patchEntity($user,$this->request->data);
    $this->Users->save($user);
}
```